# SQL Server decrementing inventory

Tags: sql-server, inventory

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a table where orders with SKU are recorded, a table for inventory that has counts and a table where the relationship between the SKU sold and inventory items is recorded.

In the end, I got the report like this

```
 Inventory CurrentQuantity OpenedOrder
   SKU1        300             50
   SKU2        100             10
```

Each order will be processed individually. How can I have the database automatically update the inventory tablet after each order is processed?

i.e

If the order has 2 SKU1 in it got processed, the the inventory table will automatically show 298.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would use a Stored Procedure, and perform the order insert and quantity update in one hit:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ProcessOrder
    @Item int,
    @Quantity int
AS
BEGIN
    --Update order table here
    INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(ItemID,Quantity)
    VALUES (@ItemID, @Quantity)

    --Update Inventory here
    UPDATE dbo.Inventory
    SET CurrentQuantity = CurrentQuantity - Quantity
    WHERE ItemID = @ItemID


END
```

Comment: i voted to your Idea, but I enhanced it with transaction control. It is very important. See my answer.

Comment: What happens if CurrentQuantity = 0? Is an inventory level of -1 acceptable to the business rules? A check before this proc runs would not guarantee that CurrentQuantity would still have a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Basically, set up a trigger that will update the appropriate columns using the inserted/updated data given. Without a full schema set, that is the best answer I can give at this time

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be looking at a trigger myself for this.

My check out process

```
Start a transaction
Check stock level.
If OK, (optional validation / authorisation)
Add a check out record
Reduce the stock
Possibly add some record to invoice teh recipent etc.
Commit the transaction
```

While you could do it with triggers, I simply fail to see the point, a nice simple clear and all in one place SP_CheckOut stored procedure is where I'd be going.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally advise to use a trigger but stock manipulation is that kind of operation that's usually done a lot of times, sometimes on batches and this is not the best scenario for triggers to be honest.

I think PKG's idea is very good, but you should never forget to add transaction control to it, otherwise you can endup with non-matching stocks:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ProcessOrder
    @Item int,
    @Quantity int
AS
BEGIN
    begin transaction my_tran
    begin try 
        --Update order table here
        INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(ItemID,Quantity)
        VALUES (@ItemID, @Quantity)

        --Update Inventory here
        UPDATE dbo.Inventory
        SET CurrentQuantity = CurrentQuantity - Quantity
        WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
        commit transaction
    end try
    begin catch
        rollback transaction
        --raise error if necessary
    end catch
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the trigger,also use the procedure,and the specific steps on the top,use the procedure need to open the atuo exec feature in mastaer DB.